# How to get an iframe to hold its position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Im having this proplem with an iframe that from JavaScript uses .load every 20 sec, and its allways moving the site in a short sec like pops up and then down,
are there somehow i can get it to hold its position??

You can see what i mean by looking at the ads on this site - http://www.pixel.tv/

the code im using to refresh it is this one

```
var adforsidetop = setInterval(function () {
    $('#forsidetop').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).load('/adsrefresh/forsidetop.html', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
}, 20000); // milliseconds
```

So how can i get it to hold the frame ? without its popping the site

Comment: Java or JavaScript? They are two completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with this is that when element is faded out element css `display:` is set to `none`, one way is to add code to set iFrame `visibility: hidden` or you can simply crate `div` that contains your iFrame

```
<div id="iframe-container">
   <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

and set css for div to be same as iframe

```
#iframe-container {
 height: xxxpx;
 width: xxxpx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your style in **screen.css** as under:

```
.fAdvertisement.fBanner {
max-width: 728px;
max-height: 90px;
height: 90px
margin: 30px auto 0;
}
```